# kivy.uix.behaviors.TouchRippleButtonBehavior's on_release not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a **boxlayout that inherits from kivy.uix.behaviors.TouchRippleButtonBehavior**, and the ripple effect works fine, however, when I define an 'on_press' or 'on_release' the functions never run. This is also true for kivy.uix.behaviors.ButtonBehavior, why is this? My Code snippet:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import TouchRippleButtonBehavior
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle


class RippleBox(TouchRippleButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RippleBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(.5, .5, .5, 1, mode='rgba')
            self._rectangle = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

    def on_release(self): # also tried passing '*args' as an argument, did not change anything
        print("got clicked!")

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self._rectangle.size = self.size
        self._rectangle.pos = self.pos

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point:
            touch.grab(self)
            self.ripple_show(touch)
            return True
        return False

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self.ripple_fade()
            return True
        return False


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RippleBox()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define any of the `on_touch_down()` or `on_touch_up()` methods you are over-riding the `on_touch_down()` and `on_touch_up()` methods that are in the `TouchRippleButtonBehavior`. The `on_touch_up()` method of `TouchRippleButtonBehavior` dispatches the `on_release` event, but cannot do that if it never gets called. The `TouchRippleButtonBehavior` methods also do the `self.ripple_show()` and `self.ripple_fade()` that your methods call. Normally, when you redefine those methods you should call `super()`, like this:

```
    super(RippleBox, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```